# Cant display accent marks or "ñ" within Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter

I have a backend built with Java and REST, and have this app in Android using Flutter, but there is an error when I am trying to display those characters.

for example instead of "Piña", the final work displays:

[image]

this is a part of the code where I am trying to use dart:convert, but not very succesful:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ProductsProvider {
  Future<List<Product>> loadProducts(
      String urlMiddleware, Client client) async {
    final url = '$urlMiddleware${Constants().getProducts}${client.code}';
    final response = await http.get(url,
        headers: <String, String>{'authorization': Constants().basicAuth});
    print('Url');
    print(url);
    json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    final List<Product> products = productFromJson(response.body).toList();
    
    return products;
  }
```

This is my model btw:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:pil_store/models/EnumValues.dart';

List<Product> productFromJson(String str) => List<Product>.from(json.decode(utf8.decode(str.runes.toList())).map((x) => Product.fromJson(x)));

String productToJson(List<Product> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
```

I am not so old with this Flutter technology, how can I display the right character?

Comment: Are you able to (using a debugger or similar) tell us what the string that should say `Piña` consists of, character by character? It could be related to an encoding issue on the way to the app from the server/database.

Comment: @nanofarad I have just uploaded a little piece of code explaining what I am trying to do with dart:convert. Perhaps can you help me with that?

Comment: could you share a sample of your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution trying something different, just fyi:

```
class ProductsProvider {
  Future<List<Product>> loadProducts(
      String urlMiddleware, Client client) async {
    final url = '$urlMiddleware${Constants().getProducts}${client.code}';
    final response = await http.get(url,
        headers: <String, String>{'authorization': Constants().basicAuth});
    print('Url');
    print(url);
    final List<Product> products = productFromJson(Utf8Decoder().convert(response.bodyBytes)).toList();
    
    return products;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some localization code for your project, so that you can view those string correctly.

To learn more about localization
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the localization you link to refers to the ability to localize fixed strings (e.g. UI elements), and shouldn't affect how an already-localized string is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that the font used supports glyphs.